# Issues In Player Movement

Tags: c++

I Wanted To Make A Tank-Based Shooting Game Using Only Text, Pixels, etc...
The issue lies in that Whenever A Player Shoots a Bullet from the Tank,
The Player is Unable To Move Until The Bullet Exits The Screen.
How Do I Fix This Issue?

Controls.h

```
#include <windows.h>

struct Keys
{
    bool up;
    bool left;
    bool right;
    bool down;
    bool space;
};

class Input
{
private:
    Keys keys;

public:
    void refresh()
    {
        //refreshs required input keys with 1ms delay
        Sleep(8);
        keys.up = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) < 0);
        keys.down = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0);
        keys.space = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) < 0);
    }
    Keys get()
    {
        //returns input of the required keys
        return keys;
    }
};

Input input;
```

Game Land.cpp

```
#include "Controls.h"
#include "Game Objects.h"

Border border(0, 0);
MainPlayer Player(102, 18);

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        input.refresh();
        if (input.get().up) Player.move(up);
        if (input.get().down) Player.move(down);
        if (input.get().space)
        {
            Player.shoot();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Refreshing.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

class Screen
{
private:
    void cls()
    {
        // Get the Win32 handle representing standard output.
        // This generally only has to be done once, so we make it static.
        static const HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        COORD topLeft = { 0, 0 };

        // std::cout uses a buffer to batch writes to the underlying console.
        // We need to flush that to the console because we're circumventing
        // std::cout entirely; after we clear the console, we don't want
        // stale buffered text to randomly be written out.
        std::cout.flush();

        // Figure out the current width and height of the console window
        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &csbi)) {
            // TODO: Handle failure!
            abort();
        }
        DWORD length = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

        DWORD written;

        // Flood-fill the console with spaces to clear it
        FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, TEXT(' '), length, topLeft, &written);

        // Reset the attributes of every character to the default.
        // This clears all background colour formatting, if any.
        FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hOut, csbi.wAttributes, length, topLeft, &written);

        // Move the cursor back to the top left for the next sequence of writes
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, topLeft);
    }
    void ShowConsoleCursor(bool showFlag)
    {
        //enables or disables cursor
        HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO     cursorInfo;
        GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
        cursorInfo.bVisible = showFlag;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
    }

public:
    Screen()
    {
        keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0x38, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x1c, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x1c, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0x38, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        ShowConsoleCursor(false);
        cls();
    }
    void setCursorPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        static const HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        std::cout.flush();
        COORD coord = { (SHORT)x, (SHORT)y };
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, coord);
    }
    void create_object(std::string sprite, int transform_x, int transform_y , int colour = 7)
    {
        HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, colour);
        //refreshs object position
        int x = transform_x;
        int y = transform_y;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (sprite.length() - 1); i++)
        {
            if (sprite[i] != '\n')
            {
                if (x < 0 || x > 140) continue;
                if (y < 0 || y > 44) continue;
                setCursorPosition(x, y);
                std::cout << sprite[i];
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                x = transform_x;
                y++;
            }
        }
        std::cout.flush();
    }
    void clear_object(std::string sprite, int transform_x, int transform_y)
    {
        int x = transform_x;
        int y = transform_y;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (sprite.length() - 1); i++)
        {
            if (sprite[i] != '\n')
            {
                if (x < 0 || x > 140) continue;
                if (y < 0 || y > 44) continue;
                setCursorPosition(x, y);
                std::cout << ' ';
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                x = transform_x;
                y++;
            }
        }
        std::cout.flush();
    }
};

Screen screen;
```

Game Objects.h

```
#include "Screen Refreshing.h"
enum Direction {up,down,left,right};

struct Transform
{
    int x;
    int y;
};  

class Bullet
{
private:
    std::string bullet = "\xDF";
    Transform transform;

public:
    Bullet(int x, int y)
    {
        transform.x = x;
        transform.y = y;
        screen.create_object(bullet, transform.x, transform.y);
        move(left);
    }

    void move(int direction)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Sleep(8);
            int x = transform.x;
            int y = transform.y;
            switch (direction)
            {
            case up:
                break;
            case down:
                break;
            case left:
                if (x-- < 3) 
                {
                    screen.clear_object(bullet, transform.x, transform.y);
                    return;
                }
                screen.clear_object(bullet, transform.x, transform.y);
                transform.x--;
                screen.create_object(bullet, transform.x, transform.y);
                break;
            case right:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

class Border
{
private:
    std::string sprite;
    const int width = 116 ;
    const int height = 41;
public:
    Border(int x, int y)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w <= width; w++)
        {
            sprite += "\xDC";
        }
        for (int h = 0; h <= height; h++)
        {
            sprite += "\n";
            sprite += "\xDB";
            for (int w = 0; w <= (width - 2); w++)
            {
                sprite += " ";
            }
            sprite += "\xDB";
        }
        sprite += "\n";
        for (int w = 0; w <= width; w++)
        {
            sprite += "\xDF";
        }
        screen.create_object(sprite, x, y, 8);
    }
};


class MainPlayer
{
private:
    std::string Player = "  \xDC \xDC \xDC \xDC \xDC \xDC\n   \xDB\xDF\xDF\xDF\xDF\xDF\xDF\xDF\xDB \n  \xDC\xDB\xDC\xDC\xDC\xDC\xDC  \xDB \n\xDF\xDF\xDB\xDB\xDB\xDB\xDB\xDC\xDB  \xDB \n   \xDB       \xDB \n  \xDC\xDF\xDB\xDF\xDB\xDF\xDB\xDF\xDB\xDF\xDC";
    Transform transform;
public:
    MainPlayer(int x, int  y)
    { 
        transform.x = x;
        transform.y = y;
        screen.create_object(Player, transform.x, transform.y);
    }
    void move(int direction)
    {
        int x = transform.x;
        int y = transform.y;

        switch (direction)
        {
        case up:
            if (y-- < 2)return;
            screen.clear_object(Player, transform.x, transform.y);
            transform.y--;
            screen.create_object(Player, transform.x, transform.y);
            break;
        case down:
            if (y++ > 35)return;
            screen.clear_object(Player, transform.x, transform.y);
            transform.y++;
            screen.create_object(Player, transform.x, transform.y);
            break;
        case left:
            break;
        case right:
            break;
        }
    }
    void shoot()
    {
        Bullet bullet((transform.x - 1),(transform.y + 3));
    }
};
```

I Tried Looking For Solutions Online...
But I Couldn't Understand How to Solve it.

Comment: Please describe in English prose what you planned to happen when a bullet is shot. Use phrases like "A ... is created and initialised to reflect ....". "Each update involves ...ing the ...". "Each update also involves ...". "This is repeated until ....". This description will allow to compare your implementation to what you intended to implement (so please do not phrase the description by reading your code). Which in turn should facilitate finding the relevant problem.

Comment: `MainPlayer::shoot` does not return until the bullet is destroyed. You need to handle the bullet in pretty much the same way as you handle the player.

Comment: So Can You Tell Me The Way To Handle The Player